write a c++ thread safe macro to time functions
I am writing a macro to time function, example below in simplified form:
namespace Tool {
   static std::mutex timer_mutex{};
   static std::map<std::thread::id, unsigned long> timers{};
   
   struct Timer {
          
          Timer(const std::string &name);
          ~Timer();

          std::string funcName;
          std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point time;
   };
}

Tool::Timer::Timer(const std::string &name): funcName(name), 
   time(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()){}
{
     std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(timer_mutex);
     if (timers[std::this_thread::get_id()] < std::numeric_limits<unsigned long>::max())
          timers[std::this_thread::get_id()]++;    
}

Tool::Timer::~Timer()
{
   std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(timer_mutex);
   if (timers[std::this_thread::get_id()] > 0)
      {
       timers[std::this_thread::get_id()]--;
       std::cout << getTheTimeNow() - time <<"\n";
      }
}

#define TIME_FUNC const Tool::Timer timer(static_cast<const char *>(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__))

void doSomemoreWork()
{
   TIME_FUNC;
   //some work
}
int main()
{
   TIME_FUNC;
   doSomemoreWork();
   //doing some work...
}


The main idea is, TIME_FUNC will construct a Timer struct and record the current time and thread, when a function ended, Timer will be destruct and i will cout the time difference between the time when construction and destruction.
The problem is, sometimes i don't get the std::cout from destructor. Is it data race or should i just not use macro ? any help greatly appreciated.

What purpose are timer_mutex and timers trying to have? They don't have any effect, unless you use TIME_FUNC in a coroutine that resumes on a different thread, where it is likely to be incorrect

TIME_FUNC doesn't create a local variable, it constructs a temporary which will destruct at the following ;

You can simplify it to this

the macro is secondary to the issue. It distracts from the actual code. Since C++20 there is std::source_location that you should use instead of a macro. Generally I advice to debug and test the code without the macro, no matter how much it is to type. Once it is working without the macro it should also work with

Note do not use std::chrono::high_resolution_clock (it can map onto std::chrono::system_clock which is NOT monotonic). For timing always use std::chrono::steady_clock

@Caleth yes it does run on diff thread sometimes. thanks for the suggestion too. I guess i don't need any mutex even if i'm runningit on different threads ?

@Caleth updated my #define, it done create a local variable

i removed the usage of mutex , it works fine now , even in different threads
